# Non-Repetitive Random Alphanumeric Code

Tags: c#, random

One of my clients wants to use a unique code for his items (long story..) and he asked me for a solution. The code will consist in 4 parts in which the first one is the zip code where the item is sent from, the second one is the supplier registration number, the third number is the year when the item is sent and the last part is a three division alphanumeric unique character.

As you can see the first three parts are static fields which will never change for the same sender in the same year. So we can say that the last part is the identifier part for that year. This part is 3-division alpahnumeric which means starting from 000 and ending with ZZZ.

The problem is that my client, for some reasonable reasons, wants this part to be not sequential. For example this is not what he wants:

> 06450-05-2012-000
>
> 06450-05-2012-001
>
> 06450-05-2012-002
>
> ...
>
> 06450-05-2012-ZZY
>
> 06450-05-2012-ZZZ

The last part should produced randomly like:

> 06450-05-2012-A17
>
> 06450-05-2012-0BF
>
> 06450-05-2012-002
>
> ...
>
> 06450-05-2012-T7W
>
> 06450-05-2012-22C

But it should also non-repetitive. So once a possible id is generated the possibility should be discarded from the selection pool.

I am looking for an effective way to do this.

1. If I only record selected possibilities and check a newly created one against them there is always a worst case possibility that it keeps producing already selected ones, especially near the end.
2. If I create all possibilities at once and record them in a table or a file it may take a while after every item creation because it will lookup for a non-selected record. By the way 26 letters + 10 digits means 46.656 possible combinations, and there is a chance that there may be a 4th divison added which means 1.679.616 possible combinations.

Is there a more effective way you can suggest? I will use C# for coding and MS SQL for databese..

Comment: Does it have to be really random or just not incrementation?

Comment: This sounds like a Homework assignment.. and what do you mean by reasonable reason..? sounds like the request / assignment is unreasonable in nature..

Comment: do you mean that the random and not repeated part is only the last one 3 chars?

Comment: Yes, it has to be not incremental and random. No, it is not a homework. Yes, only the last part should not be repeated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be random, you could maybe simply choose a fixed but "unpredictable" addend which is relatively prime to `26 + 10 == 36 == 2²·3²`. This means, just choose a fixed addend divisible by neither `2` nor `3`.

Then keep adding this fixed number to your previous serial number every time you need a new serial number. This is to be done modulo `46656` (or `1679616`) of course.

Mathematics guarantees you won't get the same number twice (before no more "free" numbers are left).

As the addend, you could use `const int addend = 26075` since it's `5` modulo `6`.

Comment: If the question is about a homework, this is probably the expected answer. It shows the teacher that you know how to use a complete residue system to solve a (supposedly) real problem.

Comment: @ft1 I would have been a great student there, then.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, while my client wants it to be totally random this does not seem like a proper solution. But on the other hand this solution will create a "randomness illusion" so it is worth to use against other solutions.

Comment: @Kadir.K If you create a fixed but random sequence, you can write it to a database table, like `{1, HYX}, {2, OS8}, {3, VVL},` and so on. With relevant key/index on the DB table, it will be extremely fast. But I don't know if it's a problem that it might become obvious to some consumers of the numbers that `HYX` is always first, and so on.

Comment: @Nielsen, while senders do not know each other following the same pattern for everyone would not be a problem. We have decided to change the addend every year so that every new year the first identifier will also change. Thanks for your solution and best regards..

Answer (score 4):

If you expect to create far less than `36^3` entries for each zip-supplier-year tuple, you should probably just pick a random value for the last field and then check to see if it exists, repeating if it does.

Even if you create half of the maximum number of possible entries, new entries still have an expected value of only one failure. Assuming your database is indexed on the overall identifier, this isn't too great a price to pay.

That said, if you expect to use all but a few possible identifiers, then you should probably create all the possible records in advance. It may sounds like a high cost, but each space in memory storing an unused record will eventually store a real record.

I'd expect the first situation is more likely, but if not, or if there's some other combination of the two, please add a comment with some more information and I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is true that there are 36^3 combinations and sender is sending approximately up to 1500 items in a year. But in the future the may send up to 36^3 items which I cannot predict from now. So there may be a worst case scenario that the randomly generated part may be repetitive for a long long time. Think about the case where the sender has already sent 36^3 - 1 items and tries to create a record for the last item, theoretically it may take forever to generate the last non-repetitive random 3 alpahnumeric part.

Answer (score 4):

I think options depend on the amount of the codes that are going to be used:

1. If you expect to use most of them within a year, then it is better to pre-generate. If done right, lookup should be really fast. And you are going to have 1.679.616 items per year in your DB anyway, so you will have to do such things right.

   On the other hand, is it good that you are expecting to use most of them? It may leave you without codes if there are suddenly more items than expected.
2. If you expect to use only a small amount, then random+existence check might be a way to go, however it is unclear what amount it should be for that to be best (I am pretty sure it is possible to calculate that though).

Comment: Thanks for your answer bu I have to repeat my comment I wrote for ceykooo's post:  It is true that there are 36^3 combinations and sender is sending approximately up to 1500 items in a year. But in the future the may send up to 36^3 items which I cannot predict from now. So there may be a worst case scenario that the randomly generated part may be repetitive for a long long time. Think about the case where the sender has already sent 36^3 - 1 items and tries to create a record for the last item, theoretically it may take forever to generate the last non-repetitive random 3 alpahnumeric part.